# Recursively Conditionally get parent Id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursion

I have two tables: `Budget Line` and `Expense`. They are structured in such a way that an expense must have either a parent record in the budget line table, or a parent record in the expense table. I need to select all child-most expenses for each budget line.

For example - `BudgetLine`:

| Id | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | TEST123 |
| 2 | OTHERTEST |

`Expense`:

| Id | ParentId | ParentType | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | BudgetLine | Group of Expenses |
| 2 | 1 | Expense | Expense # 1 |
| 3 | 1 | Expense | Expense # 2 |
| 4 | 2 | BudgetLine | Expense 3 |

Desired result:

| BudgetLineId | ExpenseId | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | Expense # 1 |
| 1 | 3 | Expense # 2 |
| 2 | 4 | Expense # 3 |

I am looking to omit expenses in the result only if they are the only sub-child. Note that an expense may have many children, grandchildren, etc.

I have tried the following, and researching various recursive CTE methods:

```
WITH RCTE AS
(
    SELECT Expense.Id, Expense.ParentId, Expense.ParentType, 1 AS Lvl, Expense.Id as startId FROM Expense 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT rh.Id, rh.ParentId, rh.ParentType, Lvl+1 AS Lvl, rc.Id as startId FROM dbo.Expense rh
    INNER JOIN RCTE rc ON rh.Id = rc.ParentId and rc.ParentType = 'Expense'
),
FilteredRCTE AS
(
    SELECT startId, MAX(LVL) AS Lvl 
    FROM RCTE 
    GROUP BY startID
),
RecursiveData AS
(
    SELECT FilteredRCTE.startId AS ExpenseId, RCTE.ParentId AS BudgetLineId 
    FROM FilteredRCTE 
    JOIN RCTE ON FilteredRCTE.startId = RCTE.startId AND FilteredRCTE.Lvl = RCTE.Lvl
)
SELECT * 
FROM RecursiveData
```

Which did in-fact obtain all the child Expenses and their associated parent BudgetLine, but it also included the middle-tier expenses (such as item 1 in the example) and I cannot figure out how to filter those middle-tier items out.

Here is a script to create tables / insert sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BudgetLine]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](500) NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.BudgetLine VALUES ('TEST123')
INSERT INTO dbo.BudgetLine VALUES ('OTHERTEST')

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Expense]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ParentType] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](max) NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Expense VALUES ('1', 'BudgetLine', 'Group of Expenses')
INSERT INTO dbo.Expense VALUES ('1', 'Expense', 'Expense # 1')
INSERT INTO dbo.Expense VALUES ('1', 'Expense', 'Expense # 2')
INSERT INTO dbo.Expense VALUES ('2', 'BudgetLine', 'Expense # 3')
```

Comment: In addition to Dale comment, please provide queries to create the tables and insert the sample data instead of attempting to describe the tables. Using these queries we will be able to reproduce the tables in no time in our server and provide solution which we tested. Thanks

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I have oversimplified, but the following returns your desired results, by checking that there is no other expense row connected to the current row.

```
WITH RCTE AS
(
    SELECT E.Id ExpenseId, E.ParentId, E.ParentType
    FROM #Expense E
    UNION ALL
    SELECT RH.Id, RH.ParentId, RH.ParentType
    FROM #Expense RH
    INNER JOIN RCTE RC ON RH.Id = RC.ParentId AND RC.ParentType = 'Expense'
)
SELECT *
FROM RCTE R1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM RCTE R2
    WHERE R2.ParentId = R1.ExpenseId AND R2.ParentType = 'Expense'
);
```

Comment: Dale, Thank you. This does not take into consideration and infinite hierarchy of expenses. It only takes into consideration that an expense can have a child, expenses can also have grandchildren, great grandchildren, etc.

Comment: @S.Walker So please update your question with sample data and desired results from that edge case, we can't guess about edge cases you don't show. How many levels can a set of expenses really have?

Comment: @S.Walker in fact you are not correct, this filter is looking for the last node in the recursive chain (which as I understood it was what you are looking for). Its not limited by how many links in the chain (at least I don't think so). But as already mentioned, provide a [mre] which covers all the edges cases and we can take it from there.

Comment: @S.Walker Perhaps you are looking for the [`MaxRecursion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-ver15) option so that you can more than the default 100 levels in the hierarchy. Infinite depth is difficult to process on practical machines, but you can set the limit explicitly up to 32767, or remove it by specifying a limit of `0`.